# Is there an easy way to bulk print wmf files?

Tags: windows, printing, bulk, wmf

I receive emails with 10-20 wmfs. How can I print them without opening all?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/) to batch print images.

[image]

Irfanview supports .wmf files

[**From their Q&A:**](http://www.irfanview.com/faq.htm#Q32)

> Q: How to print many files (batch
>   print)?
>
> A: In the Thumbnails window, you can
>   select many images/files and use the
>   menu Print selected files as single
>   images.

Comment: +1 XnView does the same ... both are available as portable apps.

Comment: Go ahead and edit it in ;-)